# Adding a label to rails date_select helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, accessibility

I'm doing an accessibility overhaul on a site at the moment and have come across a problem I don't know how to solve in Rails. The code reads:

```erb
<%= f.label :birthdate %>
<%= f.date_select :birthdate, {:start_year => Time.now.year - 14, :end_year => 1900, :prompt => true, :order => [:day, :month, :year]} %>
```

Which produces:

```html
<label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
<select id="birthdate_3i" name="birthdate(3i)">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
        ...
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="birthdate_2i" name="birthdate(2i)">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
        ...
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="birthdate_1i" name="birthdate(1i)">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
        ...
    <option value="1900">1900</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know if I have to write labels/fieldsets manually for the 3 select fields that have been produced? Or should I be using the rails code differently. I'm a bit new to rails... more of a frontender.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this on a project and we found that the only way to add labels before each `select` in a Rails date select was to monkey-patch Rails. We are on Rails 5.1.4. Here is the original method that builds the month/day/year selects and puts a separator before the last 2 selects when `date_separator` is passed as an argument:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2c97fbf6503c9199f3fe5ed06222e7226dc6fcd9/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L1091

Here is our monkey-patch that puts a legend separator before *every* date select with the correct `for` tag:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class DateTimeSelector

      # Given an ordering of datetime components, create the selection HTML
      # and join them with their appropriate separators.
      def build_selects_from_types(order)
        select = ""
        order.reverse_each do |type|
          separator = separator(type)
          select.insert(0, separator.to_s + send("select_#{type}").to_s)
        end
        select.html_safe
      end

      # Returns the separator for a given datetime component.
      def separator(type)
        return "" if @options[:use_hidden]
        field_name = "#{@options[:prefix]}_#{@options[:field_name]}"
        case type
          when :year
            "<label for='#{field_name}_1i'>Year</label>"
          when :month
            "<label for='#{field_name}_2i'>Month</label>"
          when :day
            "<label for='#{field_name}_3i'>Day</label>"
          when :hour
            (@options[:discard_year] && @options[:discard_day]) ? "" : @options[:datetime_separator]
          when :minute, :second
            @options[:"discard_#{type}"] ? "" : @options[:time_separator]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to make these `date_select`s accessible.

Comment: Just to complement the information, I saved it on `config/initializers/date_time_selector.rb` overriding the super class.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without monkey patching in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_select("DOB", :birthdate, :prompt => {
:day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year',
:start_year => Time.now.year - 14, :end_year => 1900
})
```

More options at:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: Thanks Micheal. I now see what the "prompt" option does. But what I'm really after is adding labels for the select boxes that get produced. I'm unsure it's doable, so I think I'll just wrap it in a fieldset with a legend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to generate separate labels. Even if you're willing to settle for the one label, there's the added hitch that it's not strictly valid HTML, since there's no "birthdate" form control. Are you supposed to use :birthdate_3i in the label helper?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `date_select` in a `div` or `fieldset`.  Labels can point to anything with an ID, and if you have multiple inputs which feed into one datatype, (as with the rails `date_select`) then you label the container, and let the select boxes be components of it.

```
<%= f.label :birthdate %>
<div id="birthdate">
  <%= f.date_select :birthdate, {:start_year => Time.now.year - 14, :end_year => 1900, :prompt => true, :order => [:day, :month, :year]} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that does not include patching Rails. It's still hacky though. The idea is to augment select tags generated by `date_select`. We're going to use Nokogiri to do this (requires `gem 'nokogiri'` in Gemfile).

The code below adds `date_select_with_labels` to the stock form builder that does just that:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def date_select_with_labels(attribute, options = {})
    generated_selects = @template.date_select(object.model_name.singular, attribute, options)

    selects_with_labels = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(generated_selects).css('select').map do |select|
      label(
        attribute,
        date_select_part_type_from_options(select, options[:include_blank]),
        options.reverse_merge(for: select.attr('id'))
      ) +
        select.to_s.html_safe
    end

    @template.content_tag(:div) do
      selects_with_labels.join('').html_safe
    end
  end

  private

  def date_select_part_type_from_options(select, include_blank)
    maybe_one = include_blank ? 1 : 0

    case select.css('option').size
    when 12 + maybe_one
      'Month'
    when (28 + maybe_one)..(31 + maybe_one)
      'Day'
    else
      'Year'
    end
  end
end
```